# Drawing rectangle around rendered letters in Java

Tags: java, graphics

I am having trouble drawing rectangles around rendered letters in Java.

[image]

As you can see, the letter `Y`, `1`, and `V` are outside of the rectangle. They need to be completely inside. The font I am using doesn't have overlapping letters so this shouldn't be an issue.

```
for (String word : trainingText) {
    for (char c : word.toCharArray()) {
        charWidth = fontMetrics.charWidth(c);
        charHeight = fontMetrics.getAscent();
        charX0 = xPos; //top left corner of character
        charY0 = yPos;
        charX1 = xPos + charWidth;
        charY1 = yPos + charHeight;
        graphics.drawRect((int) charX0, (int) charY0, charWidth, charHeight);

        xPos += charWidth;
    }
}
```

I was thinking that my code is too simplistic since letters in the rectangle always stick on the left. I want the letters to be centered, and this would probably entail more complex calculation.

Comment: Why not simply use a GridLayout container with a single row filled of JLabels, each label holding its own letter and using a line border?

Comment: If there is a way to create images of text using JLabel and get an array of coordinates, that would be ideal.

Comment: You might try a fixed width font, like Courier New.  The boxes will look more consistent.

Comment: `If there is a way to create images of text using JLabel` - you can create an image of any Swing component using the [Screen Image](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) class.